# There is no such getter 'click' in 'ElementEvents'

Tags: dart, dart-html

When I Run this code

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main()
{
  var button=new Element.tag('button');
  button.text="Press me please";
  button.on.click.add((event){
    List buttonList=querySelectorAll("button");
    window.alert("There is ${buttonList.length} button");

  });
  document.body.children.add(button);
}
```

Dart Editor return :

```dart
Breaking on exception: Class 'ElementEvents' has no instance getter 'click'.
```

This code is a example from "Dart in action"
I don't know what is the error.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use

```dart
button.onClick.listen((event) { ... });

or

button.on['click'].listen((event) { ... });
```

You should prefer the first option. The second is for custom events where 'dart:html' doesn't offer explicit access methods.

If you want to cancel the subscription later

```dart
StreamSubscription btnClickSubscr = button.onClick.listen((event) { ... });

if(btnClickSubscr != null) {
  btnClickSubcr.cancel();
}
```

you can also create a button using

```dart
new ButtonElement(); // instead of new Element.tag('button');
```